Superset does not allow dataset with JOIN or stored procedure
I use Superset version 3.1.3
When in sql lab I use JOIN or EXEC SP (to run stored procedures in Sql server) although it runs it won't let me create dataset based on this sql.
Is it an inherent weakness of the superset or something needs to be configured?
